# Word document to html parser that preserves all text styling (subscript, superscript, bullets, etc)

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-tika

I have read a lot of Tika guides and manual but i can not figure out how to create a Tika-Poi word document parser that preserves content styling like subscript, superscript, bullets etc. I can get it to keep bold and italic, but noting more.

Can someone give some hints how to do it or reference to some sample code?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try [WordToHtmlConverter from Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/converter/WordToHtmlConverter.html)?

Comment: I used Tika, witch internally uses Apache POI. Under the hood it will probably select that converter yes. Question is if i can get that level of details out of Tika or the only option is to manually use POI

Comment: Apache Tika has its own code for talking to HWPF to extract contents from .doc documents, the Apache POI HTML converter is different code with different aims. (The Tika code aims for semantically meaningful clean HTML)

Comment: Apache POI can keep styles by using CSS in heading. Thats like half a win. With some hacking one could extract the advanced styling from CSS.. Can Tika somehow keep the font styles as well?